# Buttons to be aligned side by side

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server">
                <div style="position:absolute; bottom:578px; left:4%; width: 6%;" >
                    <asp:linkButton id="cmdBackHour" runat="server" CssClass="configurebuttons" Text="< 1 hr" ToolTip="Go back one hour"/>
                    <asp:linkButton id="cmdBackDay" runat="server" CssClass="configurebuttons" Text="< Day" ToolTip="Go back one day" />    
                    <asp:linkButton id="cmdForwardDay" runat="server" CssClass="configurebuttons" Text="Day >" ToolTip="Go forward one day" />
                    <asp:linkButton id="cmdForwardHour" runat="server" CssClass="configurebuttons" Text="1 hr >" ToolTip="Go forward one hour" /> 
                </div>                
            </asp:Panel>
```

This displays my buttons one below the other. I want these buttons to be displayed side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below css property to your buttons.

```
float:left;
display:inline-block;
```

This will help.

Use one common class to all buttons to apply this.

Eg.

```
.btn {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vinaya,
Is there any way that i can do this in-line. I don't want to mess up with the CSC because the CSS is being used to several other buttons across our website.

Comment: Okay. Then use same property with inline css. but you've to give same property to all buttons.